# Storage of literals in Java

Tags: java, literals

Where are integer or double literals stored in Java?
Are they stored in the .class file or in permanent generation space
(now in metaspace)?

Comment: They get stored in the system's memory when the JVM executes the compiled code.

Comment: After compilation, there are no no-string literals in java.  All non-string literals are the initial value of a variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the context of your question. Or give an example, what you need this information for.

Comment: @hc_dev int x = 10; double d = 10.2 where does 10 and 10.2 stored in stack or in heap?

Comment: Probably neither.  They are probably inlined into the native code.

Comment: JVM runs these statements as byte codes. The literal values such as 10 or 10.2 are stored in operand stack which are used by byte code instructions.

Comment: You asked a similar question a couple of weeks ago; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981795/.  It is not a good idea to ask the same question repeatedly.  People remember.

Comment: And to be honest, you don't need to know this kind of thing unless you are actually implementing as JVM.  It is not relevant to regular Java programming.

Comment: @StephenC R they stored in constant pool ? Where is this constant pool located?

Comment: @user16320675 Yes where is constant pool located ?

Comment: @xyzxyz - That has been asked and answered already.  Please reread my previous comment and think about what "neither" means.   For the record, the constant pool is not in memory at all ... and it is not accessed when the application code is actually executing.   And also, read the duplink question, and people's comments on your previous (deleted) questions on this topic.

Comment: @StephenC Sure. From Java-8 permgen has been removed and method area was inside permgen earlier. So method area also has been removed or it is there somewhere?

Comment: The bytecode and native code segments will be held in metaspace.  But ... please, please, please listen to us when we tell you that you don't need to know.  It absolutely won't make you a better programmer.  I am not going to answer any more of your questions.

Comment: The phrase _Are they stored in the .class file or in permanent generation space_ sounds as if you are expecting that they are stored either in the class file or in the permanent generation / metaspace. The truth is that both are involved: they have to be stored somewhere in the class file so that the classloader can load them. And during code execution they are stored in memory (most probably in metaspace because that is where presumable all loaded class data is stored).

Comment: But note that not all literal values are equal: for some literal values there are special instructions (integer values -1 to 5, double values 0.0, 1.0 and 2.0), other can be inlined into the byte code (all byte and short values), the remaining are stored separate and referenced by the byte code.